# Example(s) for State Pattern in open source software?

Tags: design-patterns, oop

The question says all. Preferably in c# or java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Demo Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/statepattern3.aspx) that uses the state pattern